# angular-cli - dist folder not organized

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using

> angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3

How to generate a clean directory output? I have imported css files of bootstrap and fontawesome in global styles.scss.

**project/src/styles.scss**

```
// Variable declarations...

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';

// Fontawesome
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

But when I build it, all the associated fonts of the libraries are dumped into the root of dist folder, even the compiled javascript and css files too! Where can I define the path for the output assets so that I can have a neat and clean structure as:-

```
dist/
    /index.html
    /assets/
        /fonts/
    /css
    /img
    /js
```

Comment: please have a look on this angular-cli issue which has been closed. 
 https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3143